# R: How can I pass a dataframe to an object?

Tags: r, oop

I'm newbie in R and I'm creating objects but I don't know how to pass a dataframe to an object in the constructor. I have made a development but it doesn't work.

```
setClass("gComparativa", slots=list(data="dataframe"))
show <- function(object) 0
setGeneric("show")
setMethod("show", "gComparativa", function(object){

})
```

When I'm going to create the object with:

```
g <- new("gComparativa", data=dataValue)
```

I've got this error:

> Warning message: undefined slot classes in definition of
>   "gComparativa": data(class "dataframe")

Is it possible to pass a dataframe to an object? How can I do that?

Comment: `"dataframe"` isn't an S3 class, perhaps you meant `"data.frame"`? Or maybe just `"ANY"`? If you're really new to R, S4 seems like an unpleasant place to start.

Comment: I have checked that I can pass data.frame with "ANY". Thank you!!!